# Vector line parallel to $x$-axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> The points $P$ and $Q$ have position vectors, relative to the origin $O$, given by
>   $$
>  \overrightarrow{OP} = 7\mathbf{i} + 7\mathbf{j} - 5\mathbf{k}
>  \quad\text{and}\quad
>  \overrightarrow{OQ} = -5\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k}.
> $$
>   The mid-point of $PQ$ is the point $A$. The plane $\varPi$ is perpendicular to the line $PQ$ and passes through $A$.
>
> 1. Find the equation of $\varPi$, giving your answer in the form $ax+by+cz=d$.
> 2. The straight line through $P$ parallel to the $x$-axis meets $\varPi$ at the point $B$. Find the distance $AB$, correct to $3$ significant figures.

I answered the first part, but I don't the second part. Should the $\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ vectors be zero?

Comment: Perhaps a rephrase:
Are you familiar how to describe a line, containing the point $(x,y,z)=(7, 7, -5)$ and having a direction parallel to the x-axis? 

Or at least describe (in general) a point that's on that line?

Comment: The y and z values are constant?

Comment: Indeed, further elaborated by BlackAdder's answer.

Comment: Holy crap, dude! I came here looking for help about this very question!

Comment: YoussefSami ALevel Maths :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: We know $A$, and the line $AB$ is described by this equation: 
$$l: A+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Once you have this, you will be able to solve for the point $B$, and with your information on $A$, you should be able to work out the distance.

Comment: Ok, I understand this. However, I still don't get what I'm supposed to do next?

Comment: Hope my edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you have found the equation to be $-2x+y+z=18.$

We want to find coordinates of B, and we are given the information that it is the intersection point between the straight line through P and the plane.

As B lies on the straight line through P parallel to the x-axis, it will have the coordinates of $$B: \begin{pmatrix}7\\7\\-5\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

We substitute the $x,y,z$ components of this B coordinates as shown above into the equation you found in part (a), so you would obtain a number for $\lambda$

Then substitute this value of $\lambda$ back into the vector equation I gave for B above, then find the magnitude of the vector AB. Hope it helps

Comment: Your vector equation for plane II is wrong.Should be:

    2x + y - z = 8